# What right does a domain administrator have in a SBS and Win 7 environment?

Tags: windows-7, domain, windows-sbs-2008

What rights and priviliges does a domain administrator have in a SBS and Win 7 environment?

Comment: Umm... Domain Administrator rights? Did you expect something different, possibly due to UAC in Win7?

Comment: What are these rights?  Yes, you can never sure with UAC in Win7.

Comment: UAC in and of itself doesn't confer any rights. It also doesn't remove any rights. It's a mechanism for controlling the context in which applications and processes run (privilege level). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control

Comment: OK, point taken. So what are the rights of a domain administrator compared to other accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full access to anything and everything - just like for SBS with Vista or XP.

That's the environment we have here, SBS2008 with 15 Windows 7 clients and 3 XP laptops.

Comment: So the domain administrator account is like the local administrator?  Does it need to be added to the administrators group on each client machine?

Comment: Nope. Domain admins (assuming the machine is joined to the domain) are automatically local admin members.

Answer (score 0):

Domain Administrators have Administrative privileges over the entire domain.